# Adjust the main screen brightness using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscreen

I would like to adjust the iPhone's main screen brightness in code using Swift.

I know in Objective-C it can be done by:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.5];
```

How do I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617830-brightness

From the docs the proper answer for Swift 3+ is:

```
UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.5)
```

Answer (score 28):

Actually in Swift 3 `mainScreen` was replaced with `main`, so proper code is:

```
UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.5)
```