# possible to default an ios app to a certain background brightness?

Tags: ios, swift, brightness

I am trying to either default an ios app to a particular brightness when its opened. Is this possible? If so what packages do I need to use?

If this is not possible can I have a brightness scroll bar within the app itself?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264673/adjust-the-main-screen-brightness-using-swift discusses setting brightness, then just apply whatever default value you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust the main screen brightness using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264673/adjust-the-main-screen-brightness-using-swift)

Answer (score 0):

To set screen brightness, Try this code

```
UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779667/is-there-a-way-of-adjusting-the-screen-brightness-programmatically) article.

```swift
import UIKit
extension UIScreen
{
    static func setMainBrightness(brightness: CGFloat)
    {
        guard (0...1).contains(brightness) else
        {
            print("Attempt to set the screen brightness to an invalid value: \(brightness) should be between 0 and 1 inclusive.")
            return
        }
        self.main.brightness = brightness
    }
}
```